# Problem with instances in loadbalancer after deplaying ASP.net website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, load-balancing

I have a problem in the instances of the website in ASP.NET web application.

website navigate in the the way

Page1-->page2-->Page3-->Page4  and so on..

But in if some value in a drop down box in Page1 with result in the following flow.

Page1-->page2-->Page4

But the problem is ...

When i stalled it on load balancer.

it gives following flow..

Page1-->page2-->Page3-->Page4 instead of Page1-->page2-->Page4 for that particular drownselection.

It shouldn't be like this.

Please help!

I am using Active index with Multi view.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess based on what you've told me so far:

If you are storing the details of previous selections in the Session make sure the session is not set for InProc. InProc session is incompatible with most ways of configuring a load-balancer (although it can be done with various things like sticky IP or sticky session settings [if the Load balancer supports it])

Comment: In the web.config. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: If you are referring to checking the load balancer, I don't know. If I need to configure the load balancer for my system I phone Rackspace who host it for us. :)